# How to store the value of apply-template in a variable?

Tags: linux, xslt

Hi I'm using xsltproc to parse *.xsl file,

I have to store the value of

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Property[@key='Direction']"/>
```

in to a variable,

I tried

```
<xsl:variable name="mName" select="Property[@key='Direction']"/>
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is this...

```
<xsl:variable name="mName">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="Property[@key='Direction']"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

Do bear in mind though, if your template is outputting elements (as opposed to just a string value, for example), then in XSLT 1.0 you may need to use the `node-set` extension function to access the elements.